# How do I convert columns to rows only if one of the columns = 1?

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I'm following this guide to convert columns to rows in T-SQL: https://blog.devart.com/is-unpivot-the-best-way-for-converting-columns-into-rows.html

However, I need to convert only if one of the columns is set to 1.

*Table:*

```
item    milk     peanut     soy
A       1        1          0
B       0        0          1
C       0        0          0
```

*Desired result:*

```
item      allergen
A         milk
A         peanut
B         soy
```

Notice that I intentionally left out item `C`. This is because none of the allergen columns are `1`, so not needed in the final table. How do I accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `cross apply` and filtering:

```
select t.item, v.allergen
from t cross apply
     (values ('milk', milk), ('peanut', peanut), ('soy', soy)
     ) v(allergen, flag)
where flag = 1;
```